# Is it possible to access spatial graph node id of SpatialSurfaceMesh?

Tags: uwp, hololens, openxr

[Microsoft.MixedReality.QR API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/qr-code-tracking#qr-api-reference) provides **spatial graph node id** for detected QR codes. I need to access spatial graph node id of [Windows.Perception.Spatial.Surfaces.SpatialSurfaceMesh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.perception.spatial.surfaces.spatialsurfacemesh?view=winrt-19041) class *(to use with [OpenXR XR_MSFT_spatial_graph_bridge](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenXR/specs/1.0/html/xrspec.html#XR_MSFT_spatial_graph_bridge) extension)*. Is it possible?

I've tried to use SurfaceMesh.SurfaceInfo.Id property. But it seems that's not the id OpenXR is looking for.

Comment: For how to obtain the spatial node id used to enable the OpenXR XR_MSFT_spatial_graph_bridge extension, due to the lack of relevant documents and samples, I will discuss it with the internal team and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `SpatialSurfaceMesh` doesn't expose its underlying spatial graph node like QR codes or `SceneUnderstanding`, it is difficult to use the `SpatialSrfaceMesh`'s `SpatialCoordinateSystem` with the OpenXR bridge extension. And in this case, `SceneUnderstanding` mesh should be better for all purposes except occlusion. So, it is recommended that you supersede `SpatialSurfaceMesh` with [SceneUnderstanding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/scene-understanding-sdk#dealing-with-transforms) to enable the OpenXR bridge extension.

In addition, the example of this feature has been arranged into our development schedule,  please take an eye on our documentation.